# Getting Semantic Grids scss foundation 4 to work

Tags: responsive-design, sass, zurb-foundation

I have 3 sections that collapse under the default breakpoint
but I do not know how to get it to collapse with my own css using scss.

default foundation grid that works well and collapses

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 columns">...</div>
  <div class="large-4 columns">...</div>
  <div class="large-4 columns">...</div>
</div>
```

I tried below out but but it doesn't seem to collapse

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">...</div>
  <div class="div2">...</div>
  <div class="div3">...</div>
</div>

.container{
@include grid-row;

.div1 {
    @include grid-column(4);
}
.div2 {
    @include grid-column(4);
}
.div3 {
    @include grid-column(4);
}
```

}

Comment: The classes in your CSS don't match the ones used in your HTML.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain this well. The HTML is the default markup that works well in foundation 4, but when I try to have my own css in the html markup there is no collapsing of the divs. I was just showing what worked for the html default markup. I've edited the section to hopefully of made it clearer. @cimmanon

Answer (score 2):

its because you are writing the SCSS for grid-row wrong.

```
    @include grid-row();
```

Do NOT use @extend.  that is NOT how foundation4 is made to be used...  @extend just stuffs your styles into .row and .column and that is not what you want to do, instead you want to stick THOSE styles into your styles the reverse way using semantic code therefore you can change the code later in your SCSS and it updates later.

Here is the correct answer:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">...</div>
  <div class="div2">...</div>
  <div class="div3">...</div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.container{
@include grid-row();

.div1, .div2, .div3 {
    @include grid-column(12);

    @media #{$medium-up} {
       @include grid-column(4);
    }

    @media #{$large-up} {
           @include grid-column(4);
    }
}
```

}

Note: this is with foundation 5.  You must create breakpoints.  Your mobile breakpoint should have 12 columns if you want the whole view to collapse in mobile, or whatever you want.   This is the same as

```
<div class="small-12 columns"> </div>
```

if you want 4 columns for medium and up you write:

```
<div class="small-12 medium-4 columns"> </div>
```

So to write that symantically without helper classes you write this:

```
<div class="myclassname"> </div>
```

and the SCSS code is:

```
.myclassname {
    @include grid-column(12);

    @media #{$medium-up} {
       @include grid-column(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get whose answer is correct between yours (saying not to use @extend) and jofralogo's answer below, which uses @extend.

Comment: My answer is correct if you plan on using foundations built in mixins.  Foundation created the mixin grid-row() not me...  So if you plan on using a mixin SASS syntax says to type @include   extend won't run grid-row because you can't extend a mixin.   But you can extend a class, ie, .row      now saying to extend is wrong is abit harsh,  but not intended would be more correct.  Foundation intends you to use mixins if you want symantic grids.   If you want to hard code in class names or extend classes you an do that but why would you want to when you have great mixins and breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I was baffled by this, but then found out it is actually intended behavior. Here's a quote from the [official Foundation grid documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html):

> We kept media queries out of the code for our grid mixins. This will enable you to include the mixins inside of whatever breakpoint you'd like, putting you in complete control. If you want to create 10 breakpoints and shift the layout around between each one, by all means. If you want to use only the default breakpoints, we've got variables for that.

Answer (score -1):

Use @extend instead.

```
    .container{
        @extend .grid;
        div{
            @extend .columns;
        }
    }
    .div1 {
        @extend .large-4;
    }
    .div2 {
        @extend .large-4;
    }
    .div3 {
        @extend .large-4;
    }
```

I made a couple of mixins that works well and I think that makes it easier:
https://gist.github.com/jofralogo/5324278